# HTML muliple choice response not working

Tags: html, multiple-choice

I am just starting out as a web builder and I ran into a problem. I am creating a question and answer question site for training and I am having problems with the response from the answer choices, the correct answer not being acknowledge and the Critque not showing up after a response. Thanks ahead of time.

Code:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=768, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.5" /><link href="global.html.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head><body class="questions">
 <section xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="q001" data-type="Question">
 <article class="question" data-answer="D">
 <h1>Question 1</h1>
  <div class="presentation">
     <div class="stimulus">
        <p>Question stem --> Aunt May is sick with a medical history of who gives a care</p>
        </div><div class="layout q_mcq">
     <div class="prompt">
        <p>Question --> What are you going to do next?</p>
     </div>
     <div class="options">
        <div class="option" data-ident="A"><span class="ident">A</span>Answer A
        </div>
        <div class="option" data-ident="B"><span class="ident">B</span>Answer B
        </div>
        <div class="option" data-ident="C"><span class="ident">C</span>Answer C
        </div>
        <div class="option" data-ident="D"><span class="ident">D</span>Answer D
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answer"><div class="exposition">
     <aside class="objective">
        <h2>Educational Objective</h2>
        <p>Evaluate chest pain</p>
     </aside>
     <div class="critique">
        <p>Point 1</p>
        <p>Point 2</p>
        <p>Point 3</p>
        <p>Point 4</p>
     </div>
     <aside class="keypoints">
        <h2>Key Point</h2>
        <ul>
           <li>keypoint</li>
        </ul>
     </aside>
     <aside class="bibliography">
        <h2>Bibliography</h2>
        <ul>
           <li>Bibliography</a></li>
        </ul>
     </aside>
  </div>`

Comment: It sounds as if you want to send the response somewhere, so I'd expect to see a `form` element?

Comment: This is just HTML markup which won't do anything dynamic.  Presumably you have some kind of JS associated with this since I don't see any PHP or form processing code of any sort... post everything please.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can't really do form posting with just html elements. you should probably pick up JavaScript if you haven't yet, as that will allow you to do simple dynamic functions in your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `radio` button with `autopostback` set to `true` or use a `<form>` element to submit the response.

```
<input type="radio" value="A" name="Q1">Answer A</input>
```

or

```
<form action="Validate.html">
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A">Answer A <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="B">Answer B
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will try out the solutions you have requested and let you know what happens.  Again thank you.